# LOAD DATA INFILE - Desperately Stuck

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

Hopefully I can explain this well enough... I have a table called `artists` with essentially 2 columns, **`artist_pk`** (primary key) and **`artist_name`**. I am importing records for `artist_name` column via a CSV file to table `artists` using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and letting MySQL provide the `artist_pk` value.  This is all done.

Now I want to import data (via same import method) for my table called `albums`. The three relevant columns here are **`album_pk`** (primary), **`album_name`** and **`artist_pk`** (foreign key from `artists` table). Again, I will let mySQL assign the `album_pk` values.

In my CSV data I have album_name and artist_name. I do NOT have the artist_pk values. So my question is: Can I import the artist_name CSV column as part of my `tables` import, but rather than use it as is, instruct mySQL to use the associated **`artist_pk`** PRIMARY KEY value from the `artists` table?

e.g. A record in `artists` table:

```
artist_pk | artist_name  |
+-----------+--------------+
|       1 | Depeche Mode |
+-----------+--------------+
```

And now an excerpt from my CSV file (that I want to put in my `albums` table).

```
album_name  artist_name
Violator    Depeche Mode
```

'Violator' will populate `albums.album_name`. But to populate `albums.artist_pk`, I want MySQL to use 'Depeche Mode', which is in `artists.artist_name`, to go and get its associated `artist_pk` value (in this case 1) - and this is the value that will go in table `albums`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your names were guaranteed to be unique you could do it.  Otherwise you need another approach.

Comment: Not related to your question, but what happens when more than one artist is on an album?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk Thanks Dan, but I'm stuck on the approach - that was my question??? How do I access artist_pk using artist_name when doing a LOAD DATA INFILE action? And re: your second comment - collaborations would be an artist of their own (e.g. Christabelle & Lindstrom, who are both also solo artists), but compilations will be dealt with differently - I believe this is why iTunes (for example) has Artist and Album Artist. But some of this can be decided later... this whole Music database is just a meaty exercise for me to learn the ways of MySQL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `artists` table is already populated you can leverage session variables and `SET` clause in `LOAD DATA INFILE` to do necessary lookups while loading your data

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/albums.txt'
INTO TABLE albums
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(album_name, @artist_name) -- use a session variable to store a value read from the file
SET artist_pk = 
(
  SELECT artist_pk 
    FROM artists
   WHERE artist_name = @artist_name -- use a session variable to get an artist_pk
   LIMIT 1 -- this is to ensure that only one row will be returned
)
```

Let's try it out

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE artists (`artist_pk` int not null auto_increment primary key, `artist_name` varchar(12));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO artists (`artist_name`) VALUES ('Depeche Mode');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE albums (`album_pk` int not null auto_increment primary key, album_name varchar(255), artist_pk int, foreign key (artist_pk) references artists(artist_pk));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/albums.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE albums
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES
    -> (album_name, @artist_name)
    -> SET artist_pk = 
    -> (
    ->   SELECT artist_pk
    ->     FROM artists
    ->    WHERE artist_name = @artist_name
    -> );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from albums;                                                                                       
+----------+------------+-----------+
| album_pk | album_name | artist_pk |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|        1 | Violator   |         1 |
+----------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you heaps, I was almost there but had the syntax wrong. One thing though.... I had artist_name as a foreign key on `albums` but I had to remove this before the `SET` would be permitted by SQL. Is this what one would expect?